# Which driver to be used for geforce

Tags: unity, 12.10, nvidia, xorg

I have  GEforce6150SE nForce430 graphic card. i m using proprietary tested driver.
I quited open source driver(used mare than 6 months) as last time it gave me  a problem (low graphic mode ) due to this i had to reinstall Ubuntu 12.10 . i had left with only that  option(solutions on net did not worked)
so which driver is saver to use (i don't want to get that problem again )

Answer (score 1):

The proprietary driver from **Additional Drivers** (search for *Additional Drivers* in the Dash and click on the Additional Drivers icon to open Additional Drivers) should give you better performance than the open source driver. Select the Nvidia driver from Additional Drivers that has *[Recommended]* appearing after it. The recommended GPU driver is from the Ubuntu Software Center, and is supposed to be safe and run properly, and be safer than any other graphics driver that you might download from a manufacturer's website.

It happens occasionally for certain models of graphics processors, especially the newest models of graphics cards on older versions of Ubuntu, that the proprietary graphics processor driver will cause Ubuntu to boot to a black screen with a low-graphics mode message box. If this problem can't be solved in any other way, then you may have to use the open source graphics driver instead of the proprietary graphics driver.

Answer (score 0):

install "synaptic".

synaptic menu: settings/repositories/additional_drivers

choose: "using .... nvidia-319 (proprietary,tested)"

click button: "apply changes"

on synaptic mainscreen, click button: "mark all upgrades"

click button: "apply"

reboot your PC.

the above is the surest, quickest, safest way to get the nvidia driver installed and working.

to access the nvidia gui, click on the dash and search for nvidia.